# how to recursive function after executing previous recursion in jquery

Tags: jquery, recursion

**jQuery:**

```
(function loadAdminMsg() {
  $('.activated').each(function () {
     loading($(this).data('c_id'),$(this).data('offset'));
  });
   setTimeout(loadAdminMsg, 10000);
})();
```

Here loadAdminMsg will be repeated after 10 seconds but if execution of `loading($(this).data('c_id'),$(this).data('offset'));` will take 11 second then there will be a situation where one process is continuing and another process is in a pipeline that will product unexpected result. How can I confirm loadAdminMsg will be called after 10 second plus execution time of `loading($(this).data('c_id'),$(this).data('offset'));` ?

Comment: Makes `loading()` method returning promise (e.g ajax request) then use relevant deferred method, e.g, `loading($(this).data('c_id'),$(this).data('offset')).always(function(){setTimeout(loadAdminMsg, 10000);})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a callback function parameter to your `loading()` function and call it when your loading finishes.

```
function loading(c_id, offset, fnCallback) {
   // do stuff stuff stuff
   // ...
   fnCallback();
}

(function loadAdminMsg() {
  $('.activated').each(function () {
     loading($(this).data('c_id'),$(this).data('offset'), function() {
        setTimeout(loadAdminMsg, 10000);
     });
  });

})();
```